# Derivative of double integral with direct and inverse functions

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals, inverse-function

I found a couple of similar question, but I am struggling applying their logic to my example.

[Derivative of double integral with respect to upper limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304937/derivative-of-double-integral-with-respect-to-upper-limits)

[Differentiation under the double integral sign](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314065/differentiation-under-the-double-integral-sign)

[Derivative of double integral with respect to upper limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304937/derivative-of-double-integral-with-respect-to-upper-limits)

[Derivative of double integral using Leibniz integral rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102644/derivative-of-double-integral-using-leibniz-integral-rule)

I have the following differentiation of the double integral:

$$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)} (v-y)f(x)f(y)dydx$$

where $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and probability density functions.

Is it possible to apply Leibniz rule right away here to somehow simplify it? Substituting the internal integral for anti-derivatives as in the examples does not seem possible because that's a product of functions.

The best I can do is to "open up" the internal integral by integrating by parts and then apply the rule:

$$\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)} (v-y)f(y)dy=(v-z^{-1}(c))F(z^{-1}(c))-(v-z(x))F(z(x))+\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)}F(y)dy$$

Then my expression becomes something like:

$$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}(v-z^{-1}(c))F(z^{-1}(c))f(x)dx-\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}(v-z(x))F(z(x))f(x)dx+$$
$$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)}F(y)f(x)dydx$$

where the first term seems to be feasible to take, and even the second one, but the third one - back to square one. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the Leibnitz rule: If $g(r, t)$ and $g_r(r,t)$ are continuous, and $a(r), b(r)$ have continuous derivatives, then
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(\int_{a(r)}^{b(r)} g(r, t)\,dt\right) = g(r, b(r))\frac{db}{dr} - g(r,a(r))\frac{da}{dr} + \int_{a(r)}^{b(r)}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}g(r, t)\,dt$$

For your problem, $r = c, t= x, b = 1, a(c) = z^{-1}(c)$ and $$g(c, x) = f(x)\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)}(v-y)f(y)\, dy$$

Note that no condition of the Leibnitz rule says anything about products of functions. All that it requires is the $g_c(c,x)$ exist and be continuous. $b$ obviously meets its condition. Assuming that $z^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable and that $f$ and $z$ are at least continuous, that expression will satisfy the conditions. Since $b$ is constant, $\frac{db}{dr}$ term is $0$.

Therefore $$\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)} (v-y)f(x)f(y)dydx\\=-\frac{dz^{-1}}{dc}f(z^{-1}(c))\int_{c}^{z^{-1}(c)}(v-y)f(y)\, dy + (v-z^{-1}(c))f(z^{-1}(c))\frac{dz^{-1}}{dc}\int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1}f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you, I think it makes sense now... So we actually treat the internal integral as a part of the function we are applying Leibnitz rule to, right? Then even the limits of this integral obey the formula, i.e. $z(x)$ becomes $z(z^{-1}(c))=c$.

Comment: However, I am not sure how do you get $(v-z^{-1}(c))f(z^{-1}(c))\frac{dz^{-1}(c)}{dc} \int_{z^{-1}(c)}^{1} f(x)dx$. Is it because  $f(x)\frac{d}{dc}\int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)} (v-y)f(y)dy$, which is equal to $f(x)\left((v-z^{-1}(c))f(z^{-1}(c))\frac{dz^{-1}(c)}{dc} - (v-z(x))f(z(x))\frac{dz(x)}{dc} + \int_{z(x)}^{z^{-1}(c)}\frac{d}{dc}f(y)(v-y)dy \right)$ and since $\frac{dz(x)}{dc}=0$ and $\frac{d}{dc}f(y)(v-y)dy=0$ we are left only with the first term which is constant for the integration by $dx$?

Comment: That is one way of figuring it out. Though what I did was simply to note that the only dependence on $c$ was the upper limit of the integral, then applied the Differentiation theorem ($\frac d{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\, dt = f(x)$, aka 2nd FTC) and the chain-rule.

Comment: OK, thank you, and one last question about $\int_{c}^{z^{-1}(c)}(v-y)f(y)dy$. Since there is no differentiation I guess we need to integrate by parts, but it leaves one integral $\int_{c}^{z^{-1}(c)}F(y)dy$, which is unsolvable. I was wondering is there any other way to solve for this integral?

Comment: Since I don't know what $f$ is, I have no way of knowing how it can be calculated. It is true that for a generic function $f$, integration by parts in either direction does not appear to be useful. For specific functions, though, It could be easy or impossible to calculate, except by numerical methods.