# Evaluating an expression with CDF and integral of CDF

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I need to sign the equations, but got really confused with generic PDFs and CDFs.

1) Is it possible to say whether this expression is negative or positive: $F(c)(c-p)+\int_0^p F(x)dx$ if $p>c$ and $F(.)$ - CDF ?

2) Is it possible to say whether $(v-c)F(c)-\int_c^{v}F(y)dy$ is negative or positive if $v>c$ and $F(.)$ - CDF?

**UPDATE：**

Thanks everyone for your input! The question has been answered and the corollary is of a far larger scale, so I will create a new question about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your understanding in that last bit is wrong; the expected value of a nonnegative random variable is $\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx$ which I don't think can be written in that way. On the other hand, your integration by parts tells you that if $X$ is a continuous random variable and $P(X \in [0,p])=1$ then $\int_0^p F(x) dx = pF(p)-E[X]$. Perhaps that would be useful in your other problems.

Comment: The first term in the numerator has the sign of $$f(v)F(c)-F(v)$$ Why do you think this should be negative?

Comment: Additionally, if the present question is an offshoot of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161333/), providing the original formulas would be much preferable since a proof here might involve first re-deducing the formulas there.

Comment: Because CDF is an increasing function, is it not? If $v>c$ then $F(v)>F(c)$?  Also I assume that the support for distributions is wide enough so that the density function is always less or equal than 1.

Comment: You are right, it is a continuation of the question you mentioned, but the original problem has 6 double integrals and it is too much to ask to go through each of them. I will add the raw result from the differentiation of the integrals if it helps to see possible optimization. I need to evaluate the underlying function, whether it is negative or positive, at least, and my way of tackling this question was to express the derivative, but perhaps there are other ways through some implicit theorem etc...

Comment: Even probability distributions with a "wide" support can have a PDF which is greater than $1$ on some parts of the support.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Seriously? Try to have a look at exponential distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $c\ge 0$.

For $1)$, note that
\begin{align*}
F(c) (c-p) + \int_0^pF(x)dx &\ge F(c) (c-p) + \int_c^pF(x)dx\\
&\ge F(c) (c-p) + \int_c^pF(c)dx =0.
\end{align*}

For $2)$, 
\begin{align*}
(v-c)F(c) -\int_c^vF(x)dx &\le (v-c)F(c) -\int_c^vF(c)dx =0.
\end{align*}